To what extent should the research section of a tenure statement in physics be comprehensible to nonphysicists?
If the tenure review committee includes faculty from the humanities, it seems impossible to simultaneously impress physics colleagues with one's research achievements and write something meaningful for humanities faculty. What is expected in terms of comprehensibility?

If you have any questions about your tenure process, ask people in your department who have first hand experience. Not random people on the internet. That is true for most important reviews processes in life. They are specific enough that general advice is possibly useless and can even be counterproductive. Good luck!

To build off of user2705196's comment, there is a massive variation from university to university about how much people from outside one's department are involved in the tenure process.

If, for whatever reason, you have that sort of mixed audience for a single statement, start by engaging everyone at all levels to establish a connection, then move decidedly to your physics audience. The transition is where you demonstrate your communication skills. You don’t need to educate your humanities crowd; simply engage it.

@user2705196 I'm not up for tenure. I'm a faculty editor working on a tenure statement.

@rural reader: Very helpful advice. Thank you very much.

@Eggy what is a faculty editor?? And what do you mean with you are "working on a tenure statement"? Does that mean you are working on someone else's tenure statement?

The initial comment is spot on, but I think that it is a very good exercise to figure out how to explain your work at various levels, as in the "5 Levels" series that Wired produces (https://www.wired.com/video/series/5-levels).  This is not just for the specific review you are working on right now, but just for getting along in general.  I have a short description of my own work which I am comfortable sharing with my colleagues in the Anthropology department, for example.  And just yesterday, during a training, I explained the SIR model to a bunch of English faculty.

Being able to explain your field to non-experts is a really useful skill.  It makes you fun at parties, and can open doors for working with other people outside of your silo.  And thinking about how to explain a topic to a five year old can also be really helpful in developing your own thoughts on the topic, and pointing out potential flaws or holes in your thinking which could lead to future work.

Follow-up: I prompted my client to apply Rural Reader's solution and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much, and to others for emphasizing that this is an important skill.

@user2705196 A faculty editor is an editor who edits for faculty, e.g., works on papers, books, grant applications, tenure applications, job applications; grades papers; designs lesson plans; coaches disheartened scholars; writes tenure appeals; proposes dissertation skills courses; etc.
